# procedure scheduled job inside package

Tags: oracle

I have created a package purging inside that created procedure. How to schedule procedure around 2AM CST?

```
create or replace package body purging as 

PROCEDURE del_exp IS
begin

   FOR td IN (
        SELECT 
            table_name
        FROM 
            all_tables
        where owner = 'ud_oi' and table_name not like 'lgh%'
    )
  LOOP
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || td.table_name || ' WHERE TRUNC(case_dt) < TRUNC(sysdate - 38)' ;
  END LOOP;
end;

END del_exp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to use `DBMS_JOB`; if your database is *recent*, `DBMS_SCHEDULER` is preferred. You'd do it as follows:

```
DECLARE
   X  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (
      job        => X,
      what       => 'begin purging.del_exp; end;',
      next_date  => TO_DATE ('16.06.2020 02:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
      interval   => 'TRUNC (SYSDATE+1) + 2 / 24',
      no_parse   => FALSE);
   SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Job Number is: ' || TO_CHAR (x));
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

---

A `DBMS_SCHEDULER` option (which also shows how to run it during working days (at least, working here where I live)):

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name          => 'purging',
      job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action        => 'begin purging.del_exp; end;',
      start_date        => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('16.06.2020 02:00 Europe/Zagreb',
                                            'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
      repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=2; BYMINUTE=0',
      enabled           => TRUE,
      comments          => 'Purge tables');
END;
/
```

Just to mention: condition you wrote:

```
table_name not like 'lgh%'
```

looks suspicious. Table names are - by default - in UPPERCASE. Unless you create tables using mixed (or lower) case, you can do that by enclosing their names into double quotes. I *hope* you didn't/don't do that. Therefore, you'd rather use

```
table_name not like 'LGH%'
```

Comment: Thanks experts, yes we have used, table_name not like 'LGH%',

Comment: We don't have sys privileges.

Comment: If you want to use DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER, DBA will have to grant EXECUTE privileges on those packages to you.

Comment: Can we use like for 2AM CST timezone:BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name          => 'purging',
      job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action        => 'begin purging.del_exp; end;',
      start_date        => TO_DATE ('16.06.2020 02:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
      repeat_interval   => 'TRUNC (SYSDATE+1) + 2 / 24',
      enabled           => TRUE,
      comments          => 'Purge tables');
END;
/

Comment: if I make any updates to the package after the job has been scheduled will it get updated in procedure automatically.

Comment: I'm not good at *timezones*; I live & work in only one, so you'll have to find that out yourself. As of your second question, then: if you modify the package, when it is run "next time" (as scheduled), new code will be used.